# Python: How to count even numbers from a random list

Tags: python

```
import random

import math

count = 0

def print2D(list) :

    for row in range(0, 4):
        for col in range(0, 3):
            print(list[row][col], end = ' ')
        print(' ')

list = [[random.randint(0, 5) for x in range(3)] for y in range(4)]

print2D(list)
```

This is my current code. I need to create an new function which finds and counts the even numbers in the list. The even numbers don't need to add up, I just need to count how many there are. I am new to Python and my lecture videos don't help to much. This is what I have tried so far is:

1)

```
count = 0

if list % 2 == 0 :

   count += 1

print(count)
```

*num being the list*

and  2) Splitting the list. The list is random so I wasn't sure how to split the list

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it's more clear to you.

```
import random
import math
def count(list):
   return len([item for sublst in lst for item in sublst if item%2 == 0])

lst = [[random.randint(0, 5) for x in range(3)] for y in range(4)]
print(count(lst))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is one way using list comprehension:

```
lst = [[random.randint(0, 5) for x in range(3)] for y in range(4)]
print(lst)
print(len([item for sublst in lst for item in sublst if item%2 == 0]))
# [[4, 3, 4], [4, 2, 2], [5, 3, 4], [5, 1, 1]]
# 6
```

We form a list containing only even numbers from `lst`. Then, `len()` counts the number of items in that list.

Comment: Consider `sum` and a generator expression instead of `len` with a list comprehension for memory efficiency.

Comment: @timgeb But isn't `sum` adds up all even numbers when we need a count here? Sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: `sum(1 for sublst in lst for item in sublst if item%2 == 0)` :)

Comment: @timgeb oh, that's clever. You should post this one.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to theausome's answer, but without building a list:

```
>>> lst = [[random.randint(0, 5) for x in range(3)] for y in range(4)]
>>> lst
>>> [[0, 4, 5], [1, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0], [0, 4, 5]]
>>> sum(1 for sublst in lst for item in sublst if item%2 == 0)
9
```

You could also write `if not item%2` instead of `if item%2 == 0`, but I prefer the more explicit version.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import math
def count(list):
  count = 0
  for row in range(0, 4):
    for col in range(0, 3):
        if list[row][col] % 2 == 0 :
            count+= 1
print('Total Even Numbers :',count)
print(list)

list = [[random.randint(0, 5) for x in range(3)] for y in range(4)]
count(list)
```

Output:Total Even Numbers : 4

[[3, 5, 0], [5, 1, 4], [4, 2, 3], [3, 1, 1]]

Answer (score 0):

and if you want to sum all in a range:

```
    print(sum(1 for i in range(a,b) if i%2 == 0))
```